# Causal inference for spatio-temporal panel data with an continuous independent variable varying over time and cross-sections

Tags: r, econometrics, panel-data, spatio-temporal

For a research project, I have spatio-temporal panel data with an continuous independent variable varying over time and cross-sections, i.e. countries. I have recently read [this](https://academic-oup-com.em-lyon.idm.oclc.org/jrsssb/article-abstract/84/5/1969/7072904) paper by Papadogeorgou et al. and I would like to apply their methods. I have limited experience in econometric coding, so I was wondering if anyone has already done this type of analysis in R or Stata?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to analyze spatio-temporal data in Stata and want to estimate models with spatial-temporal data, there are some valuable resources you can explore. Here are three articles and one book that provide insights into the latest advancements in this field, offering both theoretical explanations and practical examples using empirical data:

- Causal Inference with Spatio-Temporal Data: Estimating the Effects
  of Airstrikes on Insurgent Violence in Iraq" by Papadogeorgou,
  Georgia; Imai, Kosuke; Lyall, Jason; Li, Fan (2022) in the Journal of
  the Royal Statistical Society Series B: Statistical Methodology. DOI:
  10.1111/rssb.12548
- How to Make Causal Inferences with Time-Series Cross-Sectional Data
  under Selection on Observables" by Blackwell, Matthew; Glynn, Adam N.
  (2018) in the American Political Science Review. DOI: 10.1017/S0003055418000357
- Toward Causal Inference for Spatio-Temporal Data: Conflict and
  Forest Loss in Colombia" by Christiansen, Rune; Baumann, Matthias;
  Kuemmerle, Tobias; Mahecha, Miguel D.; Peters, Jonas (2022) in the
  Journal of the American Statistical Association. DOI: 10.1080/01621459.2021.2013241

Furthermore, there is a book that might be of interest:

- Causal Inference: What If" by Hernán, M. A.; Robins, J. M. (2020).
  This book delves into causal inference and could be a valuable
  resource for understanding the topic in-depth.

All the mentioned articles can be traced back to the gformula by Robins. For those interested in applying the gformula in Stata, there are packages available for R and Stata. These packages can be used to estimate causal effects in the presence of time-varying confounding or mediation.

- McGrath, Sean; Lin, Victoria; Zhang, Zilu; Petito, Lucia C.; Logan,
  Roger W.; Hernán, Miguel A.; Young, Jessica G. (2020): gfoRmula: An R
  Package for Estimating the Effects of Sustained Treatment Strategies
  via the Parametric g-formula. In Patterns (New York, N.Y.) 1 (3).
  DOI: 10.1016/j.patter.2020.100008.
- Gformula: Estimating Causal Effects in the Presence of Time-Varying
  Confounding or Mediation using the G-Computation Formula" by Daniel,
  Rhian M.; Stavola, Bianca L. de; Cousens, Simon N. (2011) in The
  Stata Journal. DOI: 10.1177/1536867X1201100401